# icons missing 18.04 Flashback

Tags: gnome, icons, 18.04

I just installed 18.04 as a new install on a new disk, keeping my old home directory on a separate physical disk.  Logging on in Flashback I'm having trouble with icons not showing--most of the stock icons are showing the same generic icon instead of the Ubuntu icon for that category. I've found the main location where the icons in general are located, each icon appears to be in a distinct subfolder several levels deep.  I fixed the upper panel icons, but I can't fix the icons under Applications--even when I've located and selected the proper icon, the change isn't saved.  I've included a partial screenshot to show what I mean.

[image: screenshot showing items in the Applications menu with missing icons]

Comment: You may want to [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Do you have same problem with new user?

Comment: New users do not have this problem...and that seems to be at least a workaround to my problem--I deleted my user account, renamed the home folder, then recreated that user and selectively imported most of my home folder.  I'm still a bit curious about the cause, but it isn't a problem anymore.

Comment: For me the solution was `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` but still the folder icons are not so nice as they was in 17.04 gnome